# What is use of values-v11 and values-v14 folders?

Tags: android

I am new to android application.

Pls explain the following folders and its uses

1. values-sw600dp
2. values-sw720dp-land
3. values-v11
4. values-v14

Answer (score 12):

values-sw600dp : Smallest dimension is 600 dp or higher

values-sw720dp-land : Smallest dimension is 720 dp or higher, and is landscape

values-v11 : Version is 11 or higher

values-v14 : Version is 14 or higher

Priority is given to whichever matches best.

Answer (score 3):

You use the values-v11 and values-v14 folders in order to set up values (strings, dimens, styles, etc) for different android versions. For example, values-v11 targets android 11 and up. And you use the other two to target specific screen resolutions, and in the 2 case, a specific orientation as well.

Answer (score 2):

These are the values for specific API levels, 11 and up, and 14 and up in this case. This means that you can override specific the values in specific versions easily.

For more information, refer to the bottom of the table here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources